# How to find a recently created user - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just created a new user in my database. But before the user gets on the homepage, i check if the user was just created to show an animation to the user like below but is not doing the trick.. What could be the issue?

```
 @if(Auth::user()->waRecentlyCreated)
      {
      <div id="loader-wrapper">
                <div id="loader"></div>
                <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
          <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
          </div>
      }
      @endif

    else
    {
          //show the home page right away
    }
```

Comment: there is a typo .. missing "s" in "was".
Auth::user()->wasRecentlyCreated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you are missing `s` in `waRecentlyCreated` and You can access it anywhere simply by using `\Auth::user()->wasRecentlyCreated` and before using always first check Auth by using `\Auth::check()` in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `s` in `waRecentlyCreated`,

That should be 
`(Auth::user()->wasRecentlyCreated)`

Comment: I have updated with the missing s but when i create the new user, the function doesn't check before it shows the user the home page. It doesn't still work